# How to use conditional statement in conjunction with group_concat?

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, inner-join

I have written the following query which uses `group_concat` :

```
SELECT p.hostname AS Hostname,
GROUP_CONCAT(t2.status SEPARATOR ' :: ') AS Status,
GROUP_CONCAT(t3.error SEPARATOR ' :: ') AS Title
FROM table p
...
...
WHERE p.hostname regexp 'abc'           
GROUP BY p.hostname;
```

I am getting the following output:

```
Hostname    Status                  Title
abc.com     PASS :: PASS :: PASS    Title1 :: Title12 :: Title3
```

I want to add conditional statement such that if it is all `PASS :: PASS :: PASS` then it should show only one value under status as `PASS`
If it has one or more `FAIL` such as `PASS :: PASS :: FAIL` then it should show only one value under status as `FAIL`.
Also, it should only show `title` corresponding to the `FAIL`. For example, if it is `PASS :: PASS :: FAIL` then the output should be

```
Hostname    Status  Title
abc.com     FAIL    title3
```

In case of multiple `FAIL` such as `PASS :: FAIL :: FAIL` the overall status should be `FAIL`. The title should have value `Title2 :: Title3`

```
Hostname    Status      Title
abc.com     FAIL        Title12 :: Title3
```

If all values for status is `PASS` then the `title` should have value `NA`

```
Hostname    Status  Title
abc.com     PASS    NA
```

Comment: is possible multiple `FAIL` like `PASS::FAIL::FAIL`? What should be in `Title` field in this case?

Comment: In case of multiple `FAIL` the overall status should be `FAIL`. The title should have value `title2 :: title3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `CASE` expressions for your conditions:

```
SELECT p.hostname AS Hostname,
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT t2.status) 
    WHEN 1 THEN MAX(t2.status)
    ELSE 'FAIL'
  END AS Status,
  CASE  
    WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT t2.status) = 1 AND MAX(t2.status) = 'PASS' THEN 'NA'
    ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t2.status = 'FAIL' THEN t3.error END SEPARATOR ' :: ')
  END AS Title
FROM table p
............ 
WHERE p.hostname regexp 'abc'           
GROUP BY p.hostname;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nEigr8MJzD2fH4Wz7UcyTh/1).